# Find white spaces in the string using RegExp

Tags: regex

```
/route/some pic name.jpg
```

I need to find all white spaces beetwen `route/` and `.jpg` using RexExp.

Comment: And what is your question? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this regular expression selector. Just make sure to use the global flag (`/g`):

```
\s
```

Here is an example:

```js
var text = "/route/some pic name.jpg";
var regex = /\s/g;
var replacement = "_";

var result = text.replace(regex, replacement);
console.log(result);
```

*If you want to match only spaces, you can also just use a space  as a selector together with the global flag `/g`.*

Answer (score 0):

Regexp:

```
\s <= 1 White Space
\s+ <= 1 or more White Space
\s* <= 0 or more White Space
```

```js
const regex = /\s+/g;
const str = `/route/some pic name.jpg`;
const subst = `-`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to my answer.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qSz5WT/2 -> u can use code generator dude.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `\s` like `/\s/g`

`/g` will match all ocurrences of `\s`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace spaces with say "_" or if you want to count the number of spaces in the string, you can do something like this.

```
String pattern = "\\s+"; // regular expression for whitespaces
String str = "/route/some pic name.jpg";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "_"));
System.out.println(str.length() - str.replaceAll(pattern, "").length()); // prints 2
```

The above code snippet is in Java.